# Access appSettings Keys in Webconfig

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, iis

I'm trying to access keys in this web.config using the standard XML document read, however I can't seem to access each key. Would anyone be able to shed some light on this. I can't access it through configsettings as I normally would, because I am trying to look up everyone in IIS as opposed to just one.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <httpRedirect enabled="false" />
</system.webServer>
<appSettings>
    <add key='expires' value='expiry'/>
    <add key='createdby' value='created'/>
    <add key='DateCreated' value='date'/>
</appSettings>
</configuration>
```

The keys in the app setting like "expires" is what I need.

the C# I have is:

```
var items = drpVD.Items;
            items.Clear();

            ServerManager mgr = new ServerManager();

            foreach (Site s in mgr.Sites)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine("Site {0}", s.Name);

                foreach (Application app in s.Applications)
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine("\tApplication: {0}", app.Path);

                    foreach (VirtualDirectory virtDir in app.VirtualDirectories)
                    {
                        //Console.WriteLine("\t\tVirtual Dir: {0}", virtDir.Path);

                        String WhichDir = s.Name + " - " + virtDir.Path + " - " + virtDir.PhysicalPath;

                        if (virtDir.Path != "/")
                        {
                            string fileName = virtDir.PhysicalPath + @"\web.config";

                            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

                            doc.Load(fileName);

                            List<string> categories = new List<string>();

                            XmlNodeList nList = doc.SelectNodes("/configuration/appSettings/add/key");

                            foreach (XmlNode node in nList)
                            {
                                categories.Add(node.Value);
                            }

                            items.Add(WhichDir);

                        }
                    }
                }
```

Thank you in advance, it looks correct to me but I have a feeling I have made a mistake with the SelectNodes and my brain can't seem to fix it!

Comment: I'm assuming this is the incorrect line: 

XmlNodeList nList = doc.SelectNodes("/configuration/appSettings/add/key");

Just not 100% and can't seem to get it through trial and error thus far!

Comment: Hi jayhassett I really do not understand why you do not use this API ConfigurationManager.AppSettings ... you find yourself managing a file structure that can change from one moment to another, and challenge your code

Answer (score 0):

Why you dont use ConfigurationManager, for example:

```
var settings = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings;
for (int i = 0; i < settings.Count; i++)
{
    categories.Add(settings[i]);
}
```

Regarding SelectNodes, try to remove /add.

Comment: As he's using `ServerManager` I presume he's accessing a remote location. From memory `ConfigurationManager` can't be used to access remote instances (though I could be wrong!).